# How to synthesize date and time into timestamp type?

Tags: dolphindb

Excuse me, how can I synthesize a date and a time into a timestamp?

D = 2019.01.01
T = 18:00:18.192

Like this, my expected result is : 2019.01.01T18:00:18.192

Answer (score 0):

To combine date object and time object, please use function `concatDateTime`.